# EXCEL - Using INDEX,MATCH to find a document number.. but the document numbers are recycled. Looking to add criteria of equal to or after "date"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions to populate `Doc1` into a very large spreadsheet. I'm using `Doc2` as my match.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1'A:A,MATCH(Sheet2'A,Sheet1'B:B,0))
```

`Sheet 1
 A       B         C
 Doc1  Doc2Range  date
 123   234        3/3/07
 345   234        1/3/10`

`Sheet 2
  A     B
 Doc2  date
 234   1/1/10`

The problem is that Doc2 is occasionally recycled in the Doc2Range. I'm trying to incorporate a way so that the match is searching for Doc2 in the Doc2Range, but only pulls the number with the closest date. (The date on Sheet 1 must be equal to or greater than the date on Sheet 2) In the above example I would need to pull '345' from Sheet 1 to sheet 2

I was trying to incorporate `MAX(IF(` into the formula but was not successful.

I can't really use concatenate because the Date isn't always the same..

`=INDEX(Sheet1'$A$1:$A$100,MAX(IF((Sheet1'$C$1:$C$100)>=MATCH(Sheet2'$B$2,*******` ....this is beginning of my attempt so far..

Comment: btw, selecting the row or rows and tapping ctrl+k works as well.

Comment: Which date ? Where is the date ? Example of the spreadsheet would be helpful.

Comment: *'Number 2 can be "E1"'* yet *'Number 2's Date can be F1'*. Perhaps you could take a step backwards and develop a [mcve] that you can add to this question through an [edit] and then the question will ultimately make more sense to the uninitiated.

Comment: edited. hope this is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

This array formula is entered in Sheet2, Cell `C3`. Enter the array formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!A3:A4;MATCH(1;--(Sheet1!C3:C4>=Sheet2!B3)*(Sheet1!B3:B4=Sheet2!A3);0))}
```

- `Sheet1!A3:A4` is the range of return values.
- `1` is the lookup value for `MATCH()`
- `(Sheet1!C3:C4>=Sheet2!B3)` is criteria 1. It checks if date is equal or greater than what is stated in `Sheet2!B3`.
- `(Sheet1!B2:B3=Sheet2!A2)` is criteria 2. It looks for the value 234.

[image]

[image]

*I used "`;`" as delimiter since I use Nordic version of Excel. Users with US version should probably use "`,`".*

Comment: Thanks @wizhi ! seems to be functioning as well

Comment: Glad it could help you. :) Take care!